# add key and value to an object returned by .serialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my codes

```
var data=$('#form').serialize();
```

I want to add and key and value to `data` variable 
and I used these codes but **don't** worked

```
   Object.assign(data, {commentAdd: "commentAdd"});
 //and
    data.commentAdd='commentAdd';
//and
    data['commentAdd']='commentAdd';
```

Comment: [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) creates a String, not an Object.

Comment: @Zenoo if I sent that with ajax like this {type:'post',data:data} I can access them like this $_post['key'];

Comment: Try Parsing the `data` first and then modifying the object.

Comment: @HassanImam how to do parse?

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @HassanImam thanks but that's don't work if I use that console log me 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0'

Comment: Please share the `data` string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.serialize(); creates a string, not an object 
we can send this text like an object in ajax 
like this

```
 $.ajax({
            url:'admin/posts/comments.php',
            type:'post',
            timeout:1200,
            data:data
        })
```

to add a key and value to this string

```
 data+="&key=value";
```